# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable when trying to create substring

Tags: python

So I have this code:

```
# Imports
import sys
import random

# Data Collection
UserID = int(sys.argv[1])
KeyA = int(sys.argv[2])
PI = 3.14159265359

# Calculation
PIUserID = UserID * PI
PIKeyA = KeyA * PI
PIKeyB = PIKeyA + 4

CalcUserID = PIUserID / 9
CalcUserID2 = PIUserID - PIKeyA
CalcKeys = (PIKeyA + CalcUserID2) / (((PIKeyB - PIKeyA) * 2) + 1)

MidCalcKeyBC = str(PIKeyB / PI)

ResultUserID = UserID
ResultKeyA = KeyA
ResultKeyB = MidCalcKeyBC.split('.')[0]
ResultKeyC = MidCalcKeyBC.split('.')[1]

# Finish!
print("User ID: " + str(ResultUserID))
print("Key A: " + str(ResultKeyA))
print("Key B: " + str(ResultKeyB))
print("Key C: " + str(ResultKeyC))
print("Calc Keys: " + str(CalcKeys))
print("")
StrCalcKeys = str(CalcKeys)
StrCalcUserID = str(CalcUserID)
print("Success: " + str(CalcKeys[:len(StrCalcKeys) - 1]) == str(CalcUserID[:len(StrCalcUserID) - 1]))
```

It is supposed to calculate the KeyB and KeyC with just getting fed the UserID and the KeyA.

And when I run it like so: `python CalculateLogin.py 12 376` i get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:/Unity/Projects/Project Astra/Assets/Scripts/createCredentials.py", line 35, in <module>
    print("Success: " + str(CalcKeys[:len(StrCalcKeys) - 1]) == str(CalcUserID[:len(StrCalcUserID) - 1]))
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

right when it should say `Success: True`.

Comment: What are you expecting `CalcKeys[:len(StrCalcKeys) - 1]` to do?

Comment: Did you mean: `str(StrCalcKeys[:len(StrCalcKeys) - 1])`?

Comment: @quamrana `StrCalcKeys` is already a string, though

Comment: `CalcKeys` and `CalcUserID` are both numbers not `str`.

Comment: @OneCricketeer: My aim is to make the smallest change so that the OP and others can realise the change.

Comment: In your own words, what do you think the error message means? What part of that line of code do you think is causing the problem? Now, look at it closely. Are you using the variables you intend to use? (Hint: why does your program have separate `CalcKeys` and `StrCalcKeys` values? Which one contains a string? Are you trying to use a string in this code?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be abusing the `str()` function in order to print things

For example, you should prefer either one of these

```
print("User ID: {}".format(ResultUserID))
print(f"User ID: {ResultUserID}")
```

Then, in your success line, `CalcKeys` and `CalcUserID` are floats. Assuming they were strings and you meant `str(CalcKeys)[:len(StrCalcKeys) - 1]`, then `[:len(s) - 1]` is the exact same as the whole string itself for any string `s`, so seems like you only wanted to compare the values, which do not need to be strings

```
print("Success: {}".format(CalcKeys == CalcUserID))
```

Comment: While that is completely what I needed, I want to remove the last digit because of calculator weirdness and that is why I have the "STRING"[:len(s) - 1]

Comment: You'd need to subtract 2 in order to remove the last character. What do you mean "calculator weirdness"? If you're referring to floating point arithmetic, then you can _`round` values to a particular decimal prior to comparison_ or _`format` floats to do the same when printed_